# Rails: Shoulda-matchers belong_to optional test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, shoulda

I have a model

```rb
class Certificate < ApplicationRecord
  notification_object
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :share_class, optional: true
  belongs_to :round, optional: true
  belongs_to :company, optional: true
  has_many :approvals, as: :votable
end
```

The spec for this model looks like this

require 'rails_helper'

```rb
RSpec.describe Certificate, type: :model do
  it { should belong_to(:user) } 
  it { should belong_to(:share_class).optional } 
  it { should belong_to(:round).optional } 
  it { should belong_to(:company).optional } 
  it { should have_many(:approvals) } 
end
```

But when I run this spec I get this error

1) Certificate is expected to belong to share_class optional: true

```rb
     Failure/Error: it { should belong_to(:share_class).optional }
       Expected Certificate to have a belongs_to association called share_class (the association should have been defined with`optional: true`, but was not)
     # ./spec/models/certificate_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I do not know why I'm getting this error.

Comment: do the other optional specs pass?

Comment: @Anthony Yes it does that's why its confusing to me

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For the first, you should read [this](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/870) conversation.

> **@mcmire** We have a pre-release version out now! Try v4.0.0.rc1 to get optional.

And then, the expected code should look like this:

```
RSpec.describe Certificate, type: :model do
  it { should belong_to(:user) } 
  it { should belong_to(:share_class).optional } 
  it { should belong_to(:round).optional } 
  it { should belong_to(:company).optional } 
  it { should have_many(:approvals) } 
end
```

Comment: Are you sure? I don't think `optional` method accepts any arguments either on master and 4.0.0 https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/association_matcher.rb#L1070  https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/v4.0.0.rc1/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/association_matcher.rb#L1070

Comment: @jedi As you can see, I quoted the creator of the shoulda-matchers (@mcmire). And yes. I'm sure those words correct. P.s. v4.0.0.rc1

Comment: @MichaelArkhipov I have the pre - release version but its not working on that. Also the belong_to round and belong_to company tests are running fine so I don't know whats wrong with the first one

Comment: `optional` does not take an argument (anymore?) https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/association_matcher.rb#L304

so it is just `should belong_to(:something).optional`

Answer (score 6):

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization, optional: true
end

# RSpec
describe Person
  it { should belong_to(:organization).optional }
end

# Minitest (Shoulda)
class PersonTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  should belong_to(:organization).optional
end
```

<kbd>[Documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/Shoulda%2FMatchers%2FActiveRecord:belong_to)</kbd>